# NodeJs Execute function mutiple times without delay

Tags: node.js

i will share the code directly

```
app.get('/ListBooks', function (req, res) { 
console.log("Function called");
//internally calls another URL and sends its response to browser
request({
    url:  'someURLinRESTServer',
    method: 'POST',
    json: MyJsonData

}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("/Call Failed ->" + error);
        res.status(200).send('Failed');

    } else {
        console.log("/Call got Response");
        console.log(response.statusCode, body);
        res.send(body); res.end();
    }
```

})

now when the browser generates a request on http://localhost/ListBooks

my node console shows the first message  "Function called" and waits for internal REST URL Response

the real problem occurs only when the **REST SERVER is down**

then if i try to call  http://localhost/ListBooks from another browser tab the Node server console doesnt show any changes and only after the repsonse of previous function REST CALL call it displays console message of second function call on app.get('/ListBooks'

i thought node js makes async functions bt here i dnt want functions to wait likes this for multiple instance calls

or is it just a delay in printing message and each function call executes separately .Plz clarify ...

Comment: It's not your Express server that is causing the serialization. It's probably the rest server you're calling.  If you can log the networking, you will see that the Express server gets both incoming responses and issues both `request()` calls and sends the response as soon as the `request()` calls get their result.  So, any big delay is likely in the REST server itself, not in the Express server.  You need to find out if the REST server can actually handle multiple requests at once of it is serializing them.

Comment: yes the problem happens only when REST server is down. (sorry i forget to mention that in question. nw edited ) otherwise the request and response acts facts and console message happens like normal
 
and as REST Server is down the function doesnt execute the second function call till it get timeout on First Response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is only occurring when the REST server is down (as your comment indicates), then that's just a function of how long your calls to `request()` take to fail.  And, each separate call to `request()` goes through its own cycle of trying to connect and then eventually timing out.  If both are timing out, then you will issue request1, then request2, then some timeout amount of time will pass and request1 will fail and then request2 will fail shortly after it.  This has nothing to do with how express handles multiple requests and everything to do with how the calls to your REST server behave.

You can set the `timeout` option for `request()` if you want to shorten how long it will wait for a response, but you do need to make sure you don't shorten it so much that a busy REST server that just takes a little while to actually respond gets timed out.

> or is it just a delay in printing message and each function call
>   executes separately

Each call is acting completely separately.  There is no serialization of these responses by node.js or by Express.  The appearance of serialization is just because they both take the same amount of time to fail with a timeout so they will fail one after the other.

Comment: Ok May be Thats right, I was expecting Output Like Function called || Function called || /Call Failed -> TimeOut || /Call Failed -> TimeOut bt in real it shows like Function called || /Call Failed -> TimeOut || Function called || /Call Failed -> TimeOut evenif i tried many tab request and delay is there between Functioncalled and timout message . So thought its working sequentally not in asyn form –

Comment: @DrVishnu - If you try many tab requests from the same browser to the same host, the browser itself will limit how many can be in-flight at the same time to the same domain and will make the initial requests wait in line.  So, the browser may be partly confusing you in that regard if you are opening a whole bunch of tabs.  Usually, multiple requests are from different users in different browsers where the browser does not interfere with when the requests are sent.